# SQLite Argument out of range

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, sqlite, error-handling

I'm trying to query an SQL database and I get the following error:

> Exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was thrown. (Parameter 'name')

How can I fix this please?

```vb
Dim Connection As New SqliteConnection("Data Source = Database.db")
Dim SQLcommand As String = "SELECT * FROM Menu WHERE ItemID = 113"
Dim CMD As New SqliteCommand
 
Try
    CMD.Connection = Connection
    Connection.Open()
    CMD.CommandText = SQLcommand
    Dim reader As SqliteDataReader = CMD.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        Order.Label3.Text = reader(reader("ItemID") & ", " & reader("Name") & ", " & reader("Price"))
    End While
    reader.Close()
    Connection.Close()
Catch e As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Do not update the user interface with an open connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have too many calls to `reader` in this line:

> Order.Label3.Text = reader(reader("ItemID") & ", " & reader("Name") & ", " & reader("Price"))

Change it to:

> Order.Label3.Text = reader("ItemID") & ", " & reader("Name") & ", " & reader("Price")

Comment: Thank you. I found this solution the most basic and easy to understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

Separate your user interface code from your database code. Connections, commands and `DataReader`s need to have their `Dispose` methods called to release unmanaged resources they use. `Using` blocks do this for us. Instead of setting properties one by one, you can pass the `CommandText` and `Connection` directly to the constructor of the command. I filled a `DataTable` to pass to the UI code. The `DataTable` does nor require an open connection the way a `DataReader` does. I made the connection string a Form level variable because I expect it may be used in more than one place.

```
Private OPConStr As String = "Data Source = Database.db"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    Try
        dt = GetMenuData(113)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Order.Label3.Text = String.Join(", ", {dt(0)("ItemID").ToString, dt(0)("Name").ToString, dt(0)("Price")})
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No records returned")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetMenuData(ID As Integer) As DataTable
    Dim SQLcommand As String = "SELECT * FROM Menu WHERE ItemID = 113"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using Connection As New SQLiteConnection(OPConStr),
            CMD As New SQLiteCommand(SQLcommand, Connection)
        CMD.Parameters.Add("@ID", DbType.Int32).Value = ID
        Connection.Open()
        Using reader = CMD.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did find this too complex for my current understanding but thank you for taking the time. :)